# Hide/block/prompt close link when having a bounty

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, bounty

Since a bounty causes a question not able to be closed, can the close link be guarded some how so we don't go through the process then being prompted?

Comment: then how will mods be able to close them?

Comment: @lostsock they could get past it.

Comment: Probably should just hide the link, since we already hide it for people without close privileges.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That was my initial thought, too; but those with the privs might be confused. So, to stave off the Meta question ("Why can't I vote to close this question?"), maybe have it disabled with a tooltip?

Comment: [Related](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/07/01.html).

Comment: In my mind, a better question is why questions with a bounty cannot be closed by community vote. Having a bounty doesn't magically make off-topic questions valid. And even if there's still resistance to allowing closure of bountied questions, perhaps we could still record the close votes and make the closure happen once the bounty has expired.

Comment: @CodyGray: +1. I've once waited a week before I could hammer a question as an exact duplicate.

Comment: @Bergi You didn't have to wait a whole week. You can always flag a question for moderator attention and ask them to remove the bounty so it can be closed for [reason].

Comment: I think a good compromise would be requiring 8 votes to close a bountied question instead of 5.

Comment: @CodyGray Yes! Creating a bounty on an inappropriate question doesn't make it any more appropriate for the site. It just means that someone (probably the person who asked it) *really* wants an answer. And the reason they don't have an answer could just be because it's a bad question…

Comment: @canon [Moderators can refund bounties.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) I'm not sure if they can remove them *without* refunding them, so I can't give a definitive answer as to what happens in general.